# Подсчитать количество перестановок и сравнений при сортировке

Tags: c, алгоритм, сортировка

```
void select(int* a, int K, long double* movents,
            long double* compasion)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int x;

    for (i = 0; i < K; i++)         // i - номер текущего шага
    {
        k = i;
        x = a[i];
        (*compasion)++;

        for (j = i + 1; j < K; j++) // цикл выбора наименьшего элемента
            if (a[j] < x)
            {
                k = j;
                x = a[j];
                *compasion = *compasion + 2;// k - индекс наименьшего элемента
            }

        a[k] = a[i];
        a[i] = x;
        (*movents)++;
    }
}
```

После сортировки 10000 элементов, количество перемещений тоже оказалось равно 10000; разве это действительно так? Как наиболее точно подсчитать перемещения и сравнения?

Comment: А как может быть иначе? Вы вставляете перемещением элемент на свое место. Даже если он там уже стоит :)  У вас увеличение `movents` (кстати, зачем??!!! вы сделали счетчики с плавающей точкой?!!) в конце цикла *безусловно* - можно просто сразу увеличить на `K`... Да и сравнения у вас как-то странно считаются - увеличение только если меньше, но зато уж сразу на 2...

Comment: У вас `*movents` увеличивается на K независимо от всего остального.

Comment: @Harry,с плавающей сделал, иначе на массивах размерами 50000 переполнение int происходит

Comment: @Harry, как было бы правильней их расставить ?

Comment: Ну возьмите `long long`, но с плавающей точкой - вы все равно начнете терять эту единицу при определенных величинах...

Comment: @Elvin, для `N` элементов будет точно `(N-1)*N/2` сравнений и не более `N-1` обменов.... для 50000 это даже в знаковый 32-битный `int` влезает... да, если считать ВСЕ сравнения, а не только данных, то будет `N^2-1`, но в без знаковый это тоже влезет...

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы делал так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void select(int *a, int K,
            long long *moves,
            long long *comps)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int x;
    *comps = *moves = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {       // i - номер текущего шага
        k = i;
        x = a[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < K; j++) // цикл выбора наименьшего элемента
        {
            (*comps)++;
            if (a[j] < x) {
                k = j; x = a[j];
            }
        }
        (*comps)++;
        if (a[k] != a[i])
        {
            a[k] = a[i]; a[i] = x;
            (*moves)++;
        }
    }
}

void check(int *a, int K)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < K-1; ++i)
        if (a[i] > a[i+1])
        {
            printf("Sorting error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
}

int main()
{
    #define  COUNT 20000
    int a[COUNT];
    long long cs, ms;
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) a[i] = rand();

    select(a,COUNT,&ms,&cs);

    check(a,COUNT);

    printf("Moves: %lld, compares: %lld\n",ms,cs);

}
```

P.S. Можно сразу выдавать число сравнений как `K*(K+1)/2`...

Comment: обмен то зачем во внутренний цикл включил? да и второй раз `comps` увеличивать зачем?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Очепятался при добавлении в код автора. Спасибо за исправления. Сравнения - потому что я считаю ВСЕ сравнения, сравнение для выяснения, нужно ли перемещение - тоже. На вид O(N^2) оно все равно не влияет...

Comment: тогда сравнения из циклов забыл... а если их учитавают, то обычно считают отдельно сравнения данных и сравнения индексов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Считаем сравнения *данных*. Так лучше (и меньше перемещений).

Comment: lol, всё ради оправдания сравнения =)))

Comment: да, кстати, если ещё придираться, то внешний цикл до `K - 1` можно сделать...

Comment: @Harry,изменил подсчет количества перемещений , теперь с данным условием if (a[k] != a[i]) на 10000 элементов получается 13 перестановок

Comment: А в самом деле, какие именно сравнения имеются в виду, когда говорят о количестве сравнений при сортировке?...

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну, как мне кажется, между сортируемыми элементами?